# What are these profiled wooden objects with brass end caps?

Tags: hand-tools, tool-identification

I'm clearing my mothers basement out and came across these two items. They look like old wood working tools / templates to me so I thought I would ask you guys. [image: mystery object]

Comment: Guess: fancy winding sticks?

Comment: Is that three things, or just one thing? It almost looks like molding for something, but that only makes sense if it's one thing. EDITED: I see you said it is two. How is it split up?

Comment: Sorry I had difficulties in uploading the second photo. However, many thanks to Norcol Johnny for the spot on answer. It just give me another task, to wade through about 200+ planes to find the matching pair before they go to auction next week. I'm fairly sure they will be there, as they both came from the same source many years ago.  The links to the info was perfect again many thanks.

Answer (score 8):

It is an antique Beech Wood & Brass Sash template.

In short they were/are used as a template for creating (miter/coping) the framing around windows where glaze is used.

You can read more here. http://hackneytools.com/2013/08/how-to-use-sash-templates-or-templets/

[image]

Comment: Nicely answered!

Comment: @keshlam coming from you, I regard that as a great compliment. I thank you.